# Redirect URIs for multi-site environment

Tags: sharepoint-online, redirect

We have a multi-site environment where each site has its own redirect URL. We want to use a single Client ID and Secret for our application but register multiple redirect URIs to it. Is it possible to add multiple URLs in below registration form:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is possible solution to add on multiple URLs on the SharePoint online app registration form.

But from what i understand there is another way to achieve use a single Client ID and Secret for application and perform multiple redirects.

You can control the redirect url using the `appredirect.aspx` by specifying the redirect_uri parameter if you need to redirect from the default one check [here](https://collab365.community/office-365-sharepoint-2013-autoinstall-a-sharepoint-app-at-the/) for reference.

Basiclly it call the subsite page containing the below JS to install the app.

```
var url = String.format(
"{0}/_layouts/15/appredirect.aspx?client_id={1}&redirect_uri=https://***.azurewebsites.net/<<controller>>/<<view method containing the code to install the app>>?{{StandardTokens}}",
<<subsite url>>, "<<client id>>");

window.location.href = url;
```

The above javascript calls the appredirect.aspx page which then calls the app site as below,

```
https://****.azurewebsites.net/home?SPHostUrl=<<subsiteurl>>&SPLanguage=en-US&SPClientTag=1&SPProductNumber=**&SPAppWebUrl=<<weburl>>
```

Note: The above can be extended to check for the successful installation of the app and display an error message accordingly.

SPWeb.LoadAndInstallWeb equivalent REST / Javascript CSOM is also available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244948.aspx).

Here are some relevant links:

[Use the redirect URL in an add-in that asks for permissions on the fly](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/register-sharepoint-add-ins#use-the-redirect-url-in-an-add-in-that-asks-for-permissions-on-the-fly)

[Redirect URIs and a sample redirect page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/authorization-code-oauth-flow-for-sharepoint-add-ins#redirect-uris-and-a-sample-redirect-page)